# 'libcurl.so.4.dll': The parameter is incorrect. Rails + LibCurl on Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, libcurl, ffi

I have Ruby 2.6.0 x64 installed using [rubyinstaller](https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller2/releases/download/RubyInstaller-2.6.0-1/rubyinstaller-devkit-2.6.0-1-x64.exe) on Windows 10.

Bundler seems to work fine but I am not able to use `rake` tasks or `rails` actions including `rails s`. Error traced is given below:

```
F:\Projects\ruby\myproject>rails db:migrate --trace
rails aborted!
LoadError: Could not open library 'libcurl': The parameter is incorrect.
.
Could not open library 'libcurl.dll': The parameter is incorrect.
.
Could not open library 'libcurl.so.4': The parameter is incorrect.
.
Could not open library 'libcurl.so.4.dll': The parameter is incorrect.
F:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.9.15/lib/ffi/library.rb:147:in `block in ffi_lib'
F:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.9.15/lib/ffi/library.rb:100:in `map'
F:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.9.15/lib/ffi/library.rb:100:in `ffi_lib'
F:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/ethon-0.12.0/lib/ethon/curls/settings.rb:7:in `<module:Curl>'
F:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/ethon-0.12.0/lib/ethon/curls/settings.rb:2:in `<module:Ethon>'
F:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/ethon-0.12.0/lib/ethon/curls/settings.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
F:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
F:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
F:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
F:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
F:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/ethon-0.12.0/lib/ethon/curl.rb:27:in `<module:Curl>'
F:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/ethon-0.12.0/lib/ethon/curl.rb:13:in `<module:Ethon>'
F:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/ethon-0.12.0/lib/ethon/curl.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
F:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
F:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
F:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
F:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
F:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/ethon-0.12.0/lib/ethon.rb:15:in `<top (required)>'
F:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
F:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
F:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
F:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
F:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/typhoeus-1.3.1/lib/typhoeus.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
F:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.0.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `require'
F:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.0.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `block (2 levels) in require'
F:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.0.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `each'
F:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.0.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block in require'
F:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.0.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `each'
F:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.0.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `require'
F:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.0.1/lib/bundler.rb:114:in `require'
F:/Projects/ruby/myproject/config/application.rb:21:in `<top (required)>'
F:/Projects/ruby/myproject/Rakefile:4:in `require_relative'
F:/Projects/ruby/myproject/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
F:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:29:in `load'
F:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:29:in `load_rakefile'
F:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:703:in `raw_load_rakefile'
F:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:104:in `block in load_rakefile'
F:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
F:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:103:in `load_rakefile'
F:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:22:in `block in perform'
F:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
F:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:20:in `perform'
F:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/command.rb:48:in `invoke'
F:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:4:in `require'
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

I thought this was same as [The famous specified module](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39377541/3125070) [libcurl.dll could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44618581/3125070) error on Windows, but this one doesn't report that it's missing or anything, and seems not to react to any of the `libcurl.dll` copies (`libcurl-x64.dll`) newly placed inside `F:\Ruby26-x64\bin` or restarts :(

What parameter is wrong and how do I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried putting `bundle exec` before your `rake` and `rails` commands?

Comment: Yess, but i get the same error :(